# Format to upload images on website

Tags: file-upload, format

This question is not very technical but i think it is still right place to ask this question. 
We are creating a website like Yelp. My question is when we scan menus should those be saved as png or jpg or any other format on the server? Or what is the best way to save these kind of files? So it opens quickly without taking too much load on server for clients. 
I see restaurant pics can be saved as jpg. With the answer can you please explain also why one format should be used as compared to other?

Comment: Either format should work.  Try both and see if there's a different in performance, file size, image quality, etc.  If there's no noticeable difference, then use whichever is easier for you.

Comment: @David - Problem is we need to figure this out upfront so that we can take one direction. Also i see on yelp it opens as html now so am really confused.

Comment: So try either one and see what works best for you, that's the direction you take.  An even better approach is to design the system so that you can easily switch from one to the other, or even better... support both.  I can't imagine a reason not to support both, to be honest.  As for your last statement, what are you referring to?  What "opens as HTML"?

Comment: @David - Like if you click on menu on Yelp.com. It opens as a webpage rather then an image like jpg or png.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking.  Clicking on a link takes one to a web page generally, yes.  Is there a specific element on Yelp that you're referring to?  If they have data for a menu then it makes more sense to display it as text instead of as an image.  It uses less bandwidth, is more accessible, can be styled, etc.

Comment: @David - Well i am asking is there a way to convert an image to like webpage? Like yelp is doing? I still dont get it how their menu's are working? They must be getting menu as an image, then how do they convert it to webpage? As they are not using it as an image on their site.

Comment: There are a number of ways, but none of it is particularly simple or reliable without manual intervention.  You can use OCR software to extract text from images.  But without a really well-defined structure (such as writing a check or mailing a letter) you're going to want to do a lot of manual QA on the results to make sure the data is correctly extracted.  You don't necessarily convert it to "a webpage" but instead to strongly-typed data elements.  You'll be "massaging" a lot of data in this regard.  Acquiring and aggregating data from many disparate sources is no small effort.